# How does the fundamental theorem of arithmetic / primality tests apply to GCDs?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been asked to calculate gcd(1962,1524) which I found to be 6.

Now I'm asked to 'Verify your answer using primality tests and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

I'm struggling to see how I can link the F.T.O.A to this answer, and why primality tests would help.

Is Bezout's lemma the way to go? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Assuming you found the gcd to be 6 using the Euclidean algorithm or similar efficient method, it sounds like they just want you to recalculate the gcd the slow way: completely factor both $1962$ and $1524$ and compare the prime factors of each.  At least where I come from, this is commonly taught in elementary school (making the Euclidean algorithm a revelation when you see it in university).  That could be why the question is scant on specifics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ErickWong , but how does calculating the prime factors of each number verify that the gcd is 6?

Answer (score 1):

Completely factoring each of $1962,1524$ results in

$$\begin{align}1962&=2\cdot 3^2\cdot 109\\
1524&=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 127\end{align}$$

This demonstrates that the "common factors" include a single factor of $2$ and a single factor of $3$, resulting in the GCD of $6$.  $2,3$ are known primes, and a few primality tests will easily prove that $109,127$ are prime as well; even trial division need only get as far as checking against $11$.